# Can I extract fp-tree (any format) in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, distributed-system, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

[FPGrowth](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-frequent-pattern-mining.html) finds frequent itemsets with data-set in `Apache Spark`.
But, I really need to get a `fp-tree` to visualize my data-set.

Is it possible to get the `fp-tree` which spark constructs with my data-set?

Comment: I found it is hard to do, because PFP(Parallel FP-Growth) is used in spark. It divided transaction, and make fp-tree each node.